# Update grails plugins or reset stack on heroku app

Tags: grails, heroku

I've successfully deployed a grails application to Heroku's cedar stack, which is currently supported.

However, to generate the war it runs

```
grails -plain-output -Divy.default.ivy.user.dir=/app/tmp/repo.git/.cache war
```

which doesn't include the `--non-interactive` option so when in need of updating a plugin, grails offers the prompt to answer to this question:

```
You currently already have a version of the plugin installed [resources-1.0.2]. Do you want to update to [resources-1.1.5]? [y,n]
```

Since Heroku doesn't accept input when running remote commands, one can't answer this question and deploy is aborted.

Adding the `--non-interactive` option is highly unlikely (though it would be the preferred approach), so I'd like to "reset" the cedar stack to its initial state. Heroku's dev center doesn't help much, does anybody know how this can be achieved?

Comment: "Since Heroku doesn't accept input when running remote commands" - what command are you trying to run here? 'heroku run' does open a fully interactive session which can respond to user input.

Comment: Thanks, I tried `heroku run "grails -Divy.default.ivy.user.dir=/app/tmp/repo.git/.cache compile"` but just got this `sh: grails: not found`

Answer (score 1):

There's an option for priming your grails cache. You should be able to use it to work around this issue by checking in an empty directory and effectively clearing your cache. Just add an empty directory called ivy-cache and check it in to the root of your project.

I also opened an issue on the build pack to get the --non-interactive flag added in: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-grails/issues/15